# Installation R Debian - errors

Tags: debian, r

I am trying to download R on my virtual machine, but for some reasons I get the following error:

```
~$ sudo apt install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.3-1~bustercran.0) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.3-1~bustercran.0) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I run: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` I see the following:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/
```

And if I run `apt-cache policy r-base` I see:

```
r-base:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 3.6.3-1~bustercran.0
Version table:
 3.6.3-1~bustercran.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/ Packages
 3.6.2-1~bustercran.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/ Packages
 3.6.1-2~bustercran.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/ Packages
 3.6.0-2~bustercran.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/ Packages
 3.6.0-1~bustercran.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/ Packages
 3.3.3-1 500
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

Any idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` indicates the package repository for the main OS uses version codename `stretch`, while your R repository identifier includes the name `buster`.

You are trying to mix packages intended for two different Debian releases: Debian 9 "stretch" and Debian 10 "buster". This is **not supported** and [is known to cause problems.](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)

Debian 9 is already past its regular end-of-life date of 2020-07-06 and is in Long-Term Support which is expected to end sometime in 2022. Debian 11 is about to become a new stable version soon, so you should probably fully upgrade your system to Debian 10 "buster" before that happens, to guarantee a smooth upgrade. [The upgrade procedure is described in Release Notes of Debian 10:](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html) read it carefully before upgrade.

When Debian 11 gets released and becomes the new `stable` version, there will be a time of repository transition as Debian 10 becomes the `oldstable` and Debian 9 becomes the `oldoldstable` respectively. This might cause some temporary confusion as the new state gets mirrored to the Debian repositories all over the world. You would not want to be trying to perform an upgrade from `stretch` to `buster` while that is going on.